# R: Is it possible to turn combinations of vectors into data sets?

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, combinations, sample

I am a beginner in R.

After watching a number of tutorials on regression analysis (on youtube), I decided to make up my own data set and apply what I learnt to it. This is what I did!

I wanted to randomly create a list of salaries, ages and marital status.

Salaries

```
salary = sample(2000:3000, 250, replace = T)
```

Ages

```
ages = sample(20:50, 250, replace = T)
```

MaritalStatus

```
marSt = sample(c("MARRIED", "SINGLE"), 250, repeat = T)
```

Then, I combined the three sets of data with:

```
dataset = cbind(salary, ages, marSt)
```

Finally, I tried to run a regression on what I thought was my new data set with this command:

```
data.reg = lm(salary~ages+marSt, data = dataset)
```

... only for me to be told that there was an error and that the object "dataset" was actually NOT a dataset.

My question is two fold:
(i) Is it possible to create data sets from combinations of vectors?
(ii) If no, is there any way in R to create data sets without importing them from other sources?

Thank you very much and please I am a beginner and do not be too sophisticated in your response.

Comment: I haven't tried you're code yet but I think the repeat in sample should be `replace = TRUE`

Comment: What you got IS a dataset (an object with data). It's of class matrix. You probably want data.frame, as noted by baptiste and Tyler..

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, Alright, it's noted. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want a `data.frame` not a `matrix` (as returned by `cbind`),

```
dataset <- data.frame(salary, ages, marSt)
```

also, repeat is *not* an argument of `sample()`, you probably mean `replace=TRUE`. You would do well to read an introduction to R.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am currently reading "R in a nutshell". I started it only yesterday.

Comment: I was using other statistical packages in the past and I have decided to convert to R. I just started so I'm still a baby.

Answer (score 3):

This may help:

```
salary = sample(2000:3000, 250, replace = T)
ages = sample(20:50, 250, replace = T)
marSt = sample(c("MARRIED", "SINGLE"), 250, replace = T)
# dataset = cbind(salary, ages, marSt) #WHAT YOU DID
dataset = data.frame(salary, ages, marSt) #WHAT YOU SHOULD HAVE DONE
data.reg = lm(salary~ages+marSt, data = dataset)
```

**Also str() allows you to look at the structure of objects so you can see the difference between what you did and I did:**

```
str(cbind(salary, ages, marSt))
str(data.frame(salary, ages, marSt))
```

**Output:**

```
> str(cbind(salary, ages, marSt))
 chr [1:250, 1:3] "2388" "2530" "2518" "2450" "2008" "2502" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "salary" "ages" "marSt"
> str(data.frame(salary, ages, marSt))
'data.frame':   250 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ salary: int  2388 2530 2518 2450 2008 2502 2264 2185 2207 2048 ...
 $ ages  : int  24 21 35 31 50 39 22 21 36 29 ...
 $ marSt : Factor w/ 2 levels "MARRIED","SINGLE": 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 ...
```

***EDIT:***
baptiste beat me to this one but I'm leaving my answer up as it adds to the explanation given by baptiste

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation. I am very new to R and I wish to attain your level very fast!!! I left other statistical packages and have decided to use R and R only!

Comment: Please mark baptise's answer correct as his answer is identical to mine and was first.

Comment: who cares, yours took way more effort!